# Applying a 3-D function over a column in R

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, lapply

I am trying to apply a function that returns a list over a column. And I can't get around the "cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = False'" error. I am trying to average my data in a column using lineMeanVariance and store the result in a new column of the data frame. I have tried using as.matrix instead of list, but still get the same error.

```
aveK <- function(k){ 
    list(lineMeanVariance(k, numSeeds=5, numSteps=100)$mean)
}


amsData$k1.ave<- lapply(amsData$k1, aveK)
```

lineMeanVariance is a function from the larger code package I am working with. "An iterative algorithm for computing the Frechet mean"

```
#@param - a list of lines
#@return - A list consisting of $variance (a real number), $mean (a 
#line), $error (an integer), and $minEigenvalue(a real number)
lineMeanVariance <- function(us, numSeeds=5, numSteps=100){
```

I am trying to get $mean which is a list: double[3].

Here is a portion of my dput(head(amsData)

```
structure(list(specimen = c("FL14-01_1a", "FL14-01_2a", "FL14-01_3a", 
"FL14-01_4a", "FL14-01_5a", "FL14-01_5b"), 
k1 = 
list(c(-0.41060908075407, 0.772243365085709, -0.484809620246337), 
c(-0.150521635394175, 0.651980832267664, -0.743144825477394), 
c(-0.688516184675898, 0.335811781021467, -0.642787609686539), 
c(-0.804101914050799, 0.156301578631426, -0.573576436351046), 
c(-0.828532545265687, -0.0289329940296337, -0.559192903470747), 
c(-0.637514091418047, -0.463181099617909, -0.615661475325658)), 
k2 = 
list(c(0.714768314528387, -0.0575182499604218, -0.696992042614361), 
c(0.961496547169293, 0.271378151982945, 0.0433392248182801), 
c(0.637691066683676, 0.702459457296904, -0.316070900789642), 
c(0.547534946649107, 0.570538417729676, -0.612120409798986), 
c(-0.424748642510372, 0.683208124163481, 0.593982533213405), 
c(-0.59310308550509, 0.805082008191702, 0.0084669977181137)), 
k3 = 
list(c(-0.567454936802625, -0.630222554414604, -0.529919264233205), 
c(0.229644380354319, -0.7067727288213, -0.669130606358858), 
c(0.348742855430257, -0.629148765505902, -0.694658370458997), 
c(0.231168937750018, -0.806181892476771, -0.544639035015027), 
c(0.371887245949431, 0.72986981576373, -0.573576436351046), 
c(0.491689116363176, 0.370514325026935, -0.788010753606722)), 
site = c("FL14-01", "FL14-01", "FL14-01", 
"FL14-01", "FL14-01", "FL14-01")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = 
"data.frame")
```

Comment: Two questions:
* Where does the function `lineMeanVariance`come from?
* Could you please add a reproducable sample of your data? (use e.g.`dput(head(amsData))`.

Comment: Ok I added all that. Hopefully it makes sense

Comment: Now I am pretty sure that your error is caused by `lineMeanVariance`. If you do not want to give us that code, we cannot help you. My guess is, that you read the content of each cell and you try to take samples from it. But the content of the cell is just a string at this point and hasn't been evaluated. But without further information that guess is pretty wild.